# Using button for the trigger, after can't click the button

Tags: asp.net, button, triggers

Im using Button for some triggers, use the trigger but cant click, im remove the trigger, after  button work but page header not displayed
look ate this

[image]

`<asp:ImageButton ID="btnOderhelp" runat="server" OnClick="btnOderhelp_Click" ForeColor="White" ToolTip="Help" Height="25px" ImageUrl="~/img/help.png" />`

---

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Order No" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="arial, helvetica, sans-serif" Font-Size="13px"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtoder" MaxLength="15" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Width="348px" placeholder="Oder Placement No/Style Name"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnoder" runat="server"></asp:HiddenField>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtoder" CssClass="error" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="save" Font-Size="11px" ForeColor="Red">Order No Required!</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1" style="left: 30px;">
        <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Text="*"></asp:Label>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="btnOderhelp" runat="server" OnClick="btnOderhelp_Click" ForeColor="White" ToolTip="Help" Height="25px" ImageUrl="~/img/help.png" />
        ...
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

I tried to use `<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID ="btnOderhelp" />` but it's not working for me, I can't click the button.

Comment: Your question is still unclear? Can you explain a little in detail

Comment: Sir, im updated my question

Comment: what do you exactly mean by trigger? I kind of get it but still something is missing.Here is what I get from your question: `Button not working with trigger, Button without trigger works but page header disappeared. That's all`. But still I don't know what is it that you want?

Comment: Sir, my button not working,i want to use my button for trigger, im using it, when the used trigger for this button id, after not fire button click event

Comment: Is it `UpdatePanel Trigger`?

Comment: better post your entire html/.aspx code

Comment: As suggested by @jonju, you should include in the question the markup for the UpdatePanel, the trigger, the button, etc.. Everything that can help us to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have a `<ScriptManager />` with
   `EnablePartialRendering="true"`
2. Wrap the content you want to refresh
   with a  an [UpdatePanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel(v=vs.110).aspx)
3. Define your
   [Triggers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.triggers(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Exmaple**

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnablePartialRendering="True" runat="server" />

  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-sm-2">
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Order No" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="arial, helvetica, sans-serif" Font-Size="13px"></asp:Label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtoder" MaxLength="15" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Width="348px" placeholder="Oder Placement No/Style Name"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnoder" runat="server"></asp:HiddenField>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtoder" CssClass="error" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="save" Font-Size="11px" ForeColor="Red">Order No Required!</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-1" style="left: 30px;">
            <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Text="*"></asp:Label>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnOderhelp" />
  </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:ImageButton ID="btnOderhelp" runat="server" OnClick="btnOderhelp_Click" ForeColor="White" ToolTip="Help" Height="25px" ImageUrl="~/img/help.png" />
```

Comment: Sir, now im try this, but not work, i can post my code

Comment: Sir, <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID ="btnOderhelp" /> im using this  triggers, after cant click the button

Comment: Here is a good tutorial: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers

Comment: Thanks for this, im try for this

Answer (score -1):

Please use ajax updatepanel or set on aspx page EnableEventValidation="false"

```
  <div class="modal fade" role="dialog" id="eventdis" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatedes" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                  <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                          <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Voter Profile</h4>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-body">
                          <p>Mobile Number</p>
                          <asp:TextBox ID="txt_editVmobile" runat="server" CssClass="form-control placeholder-no-fix" placeholder="Mobile Number" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>

                          <p>Status</p>
                          <asp:DropDownList ID="drp_edits" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:DropDownList>
                          <p>Caste</p>
                          <asp:DropDownList ID="drp_editc" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:DropDownList>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                          <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Cancel</button>
                          <asp:Button ID="btn_EditVoterProfile" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="return hindModel();" CssClass="btn btn-danger" OnClick="btn_EditVoterProfile_Click" />

                      </div>
                  </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
              </div>
          </div>
```